# Why python c api does not work on apache module written in c?

Tags: python, c, linux, apache

Have a simple module written in c:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "apr_hash.h"
#include "ap_config.h"
#include "ap_provider.h"
#include "httpd.h"
#include "http_core.h"
#include "http_config.h"
#include "http_log.h"
#include "http_protocol.h"
#include "http_request.h"

#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
#include <Python.h>


static int example_handler(request_rec *r) {
    
    if (!r->handler || strcmp(r->handler, "example-handler")){
        return (DECLINED);
    }

    PyObject* py_io = PyImport_ImportModule("io");

    Py_DECREF(py_io);

    ap_set_content_type(r, "text/html");
    ap_rprintf(r, "Filename: %s", r->filename);
    
    return OK;
}

static void register_hooks(apr_pool_t *pool) {
    ap_hook_handler(example_handler, NULL, NULL, APR_HOOK_LAST);
}

module AP_MODULE_DECLARE_DATA mod_example = {
    STANDARD20_MODULE_STUFF, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, register_hooks
};
```

And compile without `apxs`:

```sh
# Compile
gcc -D LINUX -D AMD64 \
    $($(apxs -q APR_CONFIG) --cflags --includes) \
    $(python3-config --cflags --includes) \
    -fPIC -DSHARED_MODULE \
    -I$(apxs -q INCLUDEDIR) $(apxs -q CFLAGS) \
    -c mod_example.c;

# Link shared library
gcc -D LINUX -D AMD64 \
    $($(apxs -q APR_CONFIG) --link-ld) \
    $(python3-config --ldflags) \
    -shared -o mod_example.so mod_example.o;
```

The compilation is success without errors or warnings:

```sh
$ file build/mod_example.so
build/mod_example.so: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=10f64f7e7c6d0ec9301e07cb61fe5d0249653704, with debug_info, not stripped
```

But when upload to a vm machine with `apache2` installed and enable module and restart apache, says:

> apache2: Syntax error on line 146 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/mod_example.load: Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_example.so into server: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_example.so: **undefined symbol: PyImport_ImportModule**

The function is documented here: https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/import.html

Why is the python function declared in `python.h` compiled correctly but not declared on the server?, have same python and apache version (dev headers included) in host machine (ubuntu-desktop 20.04 lts) and vm machine (ubuntu server 20.04 lts):

```sh
$ python3 --version
Python 3.8.5
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0 ...
$ find /usr/include -name "apr-*" | grep -o apr.*
apr-1.0
```

Comment: The problem is that Neither the module nor `httpd` is inked with the Python library, with for you would probably be some version of libpython3.8.so.  That has no negative impact on compilation proper, and presumably the linker accepts it on account of the object being built being a shared library, not a program.  Apxs my also be providing link flags that contribute.

Comment: Yes, is in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.so`. Are you saying apache or module require preload library before start?

Comment: I writed in `/etc/apache2/envvars` the full path: `export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.so`, and works fine :D. Is there anything I can do at the library level to avoid having to load the python library manually?

Comment: You could try moving `$(python3-config --ldflags)` to the end of the link command or appending `$(python3-config --libs)` to the link command.  Probably either alternative works.  The linker is sensitive to the order of command-line arguments.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding my comments into a proper answer:

The problem is that neither the module nor httpd is linked with the Python runtime library, which for you would probably be some version of libpython3.8.so. That has no negative impact on compilation proper, and presumably the linker accepts it on account of the object being built being a shared library, not a program. `apxs` may also be providing link flags that contribute.

If `python3-config` is behaving correctly in your build environment then it is emitting the appropriate `-L` and `-l` flags already, but link behavior is sensitive to the order of command-line arguments.  In particular, you should designate supporting libraries *after* the objects that require them.  Thus, you could get the libraries named at an appropriate point either by moving `$(python3-config --ldflags)` to the end of the link command or by appending `$(python3-config --libs)` to that command.  It is not a problem for support libraries to be designated multiple times.

I am not sure what conventional practice is in the Python extension world, if even there is a convention.  `python3-config` splits things up strangely, to my eye: inasmuch as it has separate options `--ldflags` and `--libs`, I find it a bit surprising that the output requested by the first is a superset of that requested by the second.  To my mind, the `--ldflags` ought to give the linker flags, if any, that go before all object names on the command line, and the `--libs` should give the libraries that come after.  But it looks like those can be used as if their output were according to my expectations, even though that of `--ldflags` appears not to be:

```
gcc -D LINUX -D AMD64 \
    $($(apxs -q APR_CONFIG) --link-ld) \
    $(python3-config --ldflags) \
    -shared -o mod_example.so mod_example.o \
    $(python3-config --libs)
```

Comment: Thanks, but i compiled the library in same order as you command but apache can not load the python library, says `undefined symbol: Py_Initialize`, but when add the `LD_PRELOAD` from apache envvars works fine. The compilation command is not work.